# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'string_join'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm reading an introductory book to tensorflow and encountered an error with the first code snippet.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf


msg = tf.string_join(["Hello ", "TensorFlow"])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(msg))
```

This is the output from the console:

```
2020-12-18 13:30:58.723487: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2020-12-18 13:30:58.727081: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensor.py", line 7, in <module>
    msg = tf.string_join(["Hello ", "TensorFlow"])
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'string_join'
```

Any help would be greatly apppreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string_join` seems to be from [Tensorflow 1](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/strings/join).  Notice the alias of `string_join` for `tf.strings.join`.

However in [Tensorflow 2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/join) they no longer have that alias.  They do have an alias for `tf.compat.v1.string_join`.  But it looks like you can probably just `tf.strings.join`

Example code from those docs

```
tf.strings.join(['abc','def']).numpy()

tf.strings.join([['abc','123'],
                 ['def','456'],
                 ['ghi','789']]).numpy()

tf.strings.join([['abc','123'],
                 ['def','456']],
                 separator=" ").numpy()
```